# js-beautify for html has no method 'beautify'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, js-beautify

I am trying to use `js-beautify` for `html` in a `node.js` application:

```
var htmlBeautifier = require('js-beautify').html;
...
res = htmlBeautifier.beautify(html);
...
```

But I get:

```
...
res = htmlBeautifier.beautify(html,{});
                         ^
TypeError: Object function (html_source, options) {
    return style_html(html_source, options, js_beautify.js_beautify, css_beautify.css_beautify);
} has no method 'beautify'
```

The documentation about using `js-beautify` for `html` does not provide much information. How is one supposed to use `js-beautify` for `html`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/js-beautify) (which could do with a bit more detail), `html` **is** the function, not an object with the function as a property. So:

```
var htmlBeautifier = require('js-beautify').html;
//...
res = htmlBeautifier(html);
```

or

```
var htmlBeautifier = require('js-beautify');
//...
res = htmlBeautifier.html(html);
```

Comment: ...and now I've tested it, not just relied on the doc. Either of the above is fine.